# Existe relação entre Ciência de dados e Analise de dados?

Tags: terminologia, ciência-de-dados

Estava lendo a respeito de [analise de dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_de_dados) e fiquei com uma dúvida em relação ao conceito *ciência de dados* e *analise de dados*. Não consigo ver diferenças entre os dois termos, ambos me parecem a mesma coisa.

## Dúvida

Qual é a relação entre ciência de dados e analise de dados? Existe diferenças? São independentes um do outro?

Answer (score 1):

Embora os conhecimentos necessários e ferramentas utilizadas por ambos seja muito parecido (estatística, matemática, programação e conhecimento do negócio), eles não são a mesma coisa.

**Análise de dados** é processar os dados para realizar análises (geralmente estatísticas) para validar hipóteses, tirar conclusões e ajudar na tomada de decisão. Genericamente falando, os passos para fazer uma análise são:

1. Entender qual é pergunta a ser respondida pela análise, ou seja, o que se deseja saber com aquela análise.
2. Entender seus dados e estabelecer suas premissas.
3. Levantar hipóteses.
4. Validar as hipóteses levantadas
5. Tirar conclusões

Um exemplo é analisar a venda de um produto e ver qual tipo de abordagem de marketing é mais eficiente.

**Ciência de dados** "visa a extração de conhecimento, detecção de padrões e/ou obtenção de insights para possíveis tomadas de decisão". Para isso, capturar, armazenar e processar (seja por análises ou desenvolvendo modelos) os dados são possíveis etapas de um projeto. Ou seja, a ciência de dados engloba a análise de dados.

**Bibliografia:**

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_de_dados

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ci%C3%AAncia_de_dados

http://datascienceacademy.com.br/blog/qual-a-diferenca-entre-o-analista-de-bi-e-o-cientista-de-dados/

https://fia.com.br/blog/ciencia-de-dados-data-science/

https://www.fm2s.com.br/analise-de-dados-como-estruturar/